# Software / library to make interactive mechanical unit animation

Tags: 3d, game-development, animation, modeling

I would like to make an educational game or a 3d model (I'm not sure, that's actually why I'm here :-)
I have zero experience in 3d modeling, some knowledge of Python and JavaScript.
I want to build a game / program (or maybe just a 3d model) that will demonstrate different mechanical units of various vehicles, like so:

[2 stroke engine animation video](https://inv.tux.pizza/watch?v=kWRRHRWuduk)

**BUT** with ability to make certain parts opaque or transparent, to start or stop the unit, to tweak it various parameters, to zoom in/out or move camera.

Representation of a unit should be as accurate, from physics point of view, as possible.

I've researched the subject a bit, as far as I understood I have the following options:

1. Use some 3d modeling software (e.g. [Blender](https://www.blender.org/)), as far as I understood, once accurate, in-depth model is made - everything I want can be done with it (no need to write some sort of environment for it - to manipulate the unit, move camera etc.; or am I wrong here?
2. Use a 3d modeling library (in my case for Python or JS). As far as I understood, in this case the model itself, anyway will have to be made in some external program ([Blender](https://www.blender.org/) etc.), or am I wrong here? This way I will be able to customize everything about model manipulation.

The questions are:

1. Are there any other ways to achieve desired, I didn't think of?
2. Which way, likely, would be the most efficient (i.e. will take the least time) in my situation?

Comment: @RohitGupta, please **read** the sentence (I mean second question, you are refering to), you will see that it says: "... most efficient (i.e. **will take the least time**) **in my situation**?"

Comment: Blender is capable of doing such animations without coding, they may optionally be scripted with Python if required. FreeCAD is more adequate for this type of engineering models, or ou may also use something like OpenSCAD if you wish to model everything through scripting. For animation and visualization, you will still likely have to use something else, like Blender, since both CAD programs are comparatively limited renreingwise if you want something fancier.